# Draw a graph in R with header elaborate on two columns

Tags: r, graph, 3d

I have a table with header expanded on two columns. How to draw a 3D graph on this table OR what would be a way to draw a graph on tables having elaborated headers. Kindly suggest me alternate ways to achieve this (if any)

**Crime Table**:

```
year                                                 
                 2014              2015              2016             
                 Reported Detected Reported Detected Reported Detected
 Murder          221      208      178      172      26       20      
 Murder(Gain)     20       16       11        9       1        1      
 Dacoity          51       45       44       36       5        1      
 Robbery         538      316      351      201      23       10      
 Chain Snatching 528      394      342      229      23        0
```

**Code**:

```
library(tables)
#CLASS 1 CRIMES 2014
c14 <- structure(list(`Reported` = c(221, 20, 51, 
                                      538, 528), `Detected` = c(208, 16, 45, 316, 394)), .Names = c("Reported", 
                                                                                          "Detected"), row.names = c("Murder", "Murder(Gain)", "Dacoity", "Robbery", "Chain Snatching"), class = "data.frame")

c14

#CLASS 1 CRIMES 2015

c15 <- structure(list(`Reported` = c(178, 11, 44, 
                                     351, 342), `Detected` = c(172, 9, 
                                                                    36, 201, 229)), .Names = c("Reported", 
                                                                                                      "Detected"), row.names = c("Murder", "Murder(Gain)", "Dacoity", 
                                                                                                                                 "Robbery", "Chain Snatching"), class = "data.frame")
c15

#CLASS 1 CRIMES 31-01-2016
c16 <- structure(list(`Reported` = c(26, 1, 5, 
                                     23, 23), `Detected` = c(20, 1, 
                                                               1, 10, 0)), .Names = c("Reported", 
                                                                                          "Detected"), row.names = c("Murder", "Murder(Gain)", "Dacoity", 
                                                                                                                     "Robbery", "Chain Snatching"), class = "data.frame")
c16


# rbind with rownames as a column 
st <- rbind(
  data.frame(c14, year = '2014', what = factor(rownames(c14), levels = rownames(c14)), 
             row.names= NULL, check.names = FALSE), 
  data.frame(c15,year = '2015',what = factor(rownames(c15), levels = rownames(c15)), 
             row.names = NULL,check.names = FALSE),
  data.frame(c16,year = '2016',what = factor(rownames(c16), levels = rownames(c16)), 
             row.names = NULL,check.names = FALSE)
)

crimetable <- tabular(Heading()*what ~ year*(`Reported` +`Detected`)*Heading()*(identity),data=st)
crimetable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I hate 3D plots for 3-way tables and I like ggplot2, I suggest this:

Gather your data into "long" format:

```
library(tidyr)
st_long = gather(st, type, count, -c(year, what))
head(st_long, 3)
#   year         what     type count
# 1 2014       Murder Reported   221
# 2 2014 Murder(Gain) Reported    20
# 3 2014      Dacoity Reported    51
```

As you can see, both `Detected` and `Reported` columns are now included in the same column called `type`. This is useful for `ggplot2`, as it can easily create facets. Facets are separate elements within the plot that share the same aesthetic components but work with on different groups of data:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(st_long, aes(year, count, group = what, color = what)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ type)
```

(I am not saying that line plot is the only/best plot here, but it is often used when comparing frequencies across different time-points.)

Comment: Thanks for the help